# Slight generalization of the First Isomorphism Theorem

Tags: group-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

I'm being asked to prove the following generalization of the First Isomorphism Theorem:

If $f:G \mapsto H$ is a homomorphism, and $N $ is a normal subgroup of $G$ contained in $ker(f)$, with $\pi$ as the quotient homomorphism, that there exists a unique homomorphism $f':G/N \mapsto H$ with $f' \pi =f$

As far as I can tell this is almost identical to the first isomorphism theorem with the only major difference being that $N$ is not equal to the kernel. At first glance, this makes me think that this may disrupt $f'$ being well defined, but since proving that it is depends on all $n$ in $N$ having the property that $f(n)=e$ (the identity element in G), but if $N$ is contained in the kernel, that would take care of itself.

Is there something else I'm missing? I find it unlikely that I'm just being asked to spew back a proof we've already seen in class?

I will also add, I understand that if $f$ is surjective we will see $f'$ mapping to $H$ and if $f$ is not surjective, we'll be mapping to $Img(f)$ instead, and I'm not sure if this is a strange way of asking about that generalization.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think this is sometimes people call this 'factor theorem', but it's not incredibly common. The theorem itself does seem to get invoked quite a bit, at least in opinion. People typically don't explicitly cite the theorem when they apply it.

Comment: To my knowledge the isomorphism theorem doesn't assert anything about a unique morphism, or anything about commutativity of morphisms. Sometimes this theorem can be best understood by drawing a picture called a 'commutative diagram'. I have never actually figured out how to latex a diagram on MSE, so I can't post it as an answer but if I figure it out I will! Basically, if you are working with a morphism that you know very little about it but you show that it satisfies that commutativity, by uniqueness you immediately know what map it is

Comment: Or going the other direction, if you are trying to induce a map between two things and you know that your normal subgroup is contained in the kernel of some other map, you always know that the map asserted in the theorem exists, so you get that for free via this result.

Comment: Is your question about how to prove it, or why it's different? Have you tried proving it yet? Just proving it will probably make the differences between the two clear. Also, your claim about what happens when $f$ is surjective doesn't really make sense for this theorem. What you said is true for the first isomorphism theorem, but in this theorem $f'$ is always a map to $H$.

Answer (score 1):

This result is quite similar to the first isomorphism theorem, but with some minor subtleties, which are not so obvious (to me, at least) and can be instructive. What follows is a sketch of the proof.

Let $\bar{f}: G/\ker(f) \to H$ be the unique morphism such that $\bar{f}\pi_{\ker(f)} = f$, given by the first isomorphism theorem. Given $N \subseteq \ker(f), N \triangleleft G$, we always have a morphism

$$
\tau : G/N \longrightarrow G/\ker(f) \\
gN \mapsto g\cdot\ker(f)
$$

Now,  we can take $f' = \bar{f}\tau$, since for every $g \in G$,

$$
f'\pi(g) = f'(gN) = \bar{f}\tau(gN) = \bar{f}(g\ker(f)) = \bar{f}\pi_{\ker(f)}(g) = f(g)
$$

and the uniqueness is given by the following fact: since $\pi$ is an epimorphism, it is right cancellative, that is $g\pi = h\pi$ implies $g = h$. In particular if we have another morphism $f'':G/N \to H$ such that $f''\pi = f$, then

$$
f''\pi = f = f'\pi
$$

and so $f'' = f'$.

As you said, we're very strongly using that $N \subseteq \ker(f)$, but nevertheless there are still some remarks to be made.

I've also noted that you talked about $f'$ being surjective or not, sometimes the first isomorphism theorem is stated for surjective morphisms, so that we get $G/\ker(f) \simeq H$, but more generally, if you have a morphism $\phi:G \to H$, by the first isomorphism theorem we have a morphism $\phi': G/\ker(f) \to \operatorname{im}(f)$ with $\phi'\pi = \phi$, by taking $\iota\phi'$ with $\iota:im(f) \to H$ the inclusion map, you now have a (non-necessarily surjective) morphism $\iota\phi':G \to H$, which is unique (we can again invoke that $\pi$ is right cancellative) and satisfies $\iota\phi'\pi = \phi$.

Answer (score 0):

This proof is going to be an introduction to diagram chasing. I suggest you try it yourself first, it was really fun to do. I'll list the full proof out below (doesn't require reproving first iso theorem, but uses it quite a bit). The question that's really being asked is why do we get a *unique* homomorphism $f':G/N\to H$.

I suggest you draw out a diagram of the maps/groups I'm about to say. Your diagram should have G,H,G/N and G/K for the groups, where $K$ denotes $\ker(f)$.  I'll list out the maps along the way of the proof, although you could probably guess half the maps off the bat.

The basic idea is to factor $\pi_K:G\to G/K$ into $\pi_K=\star \circ \pi_N$ where $\star:G/N\to G/K$ denotes some map I'll define in a second. We know that by first iso, there exists an unique $\tilde{f}$ such that $f=\tilde{f}\circ \pi_K$. You're going to define $f'=\tilde{f}\circ \star$. I claim that $\star$ is well defined (as a group homomorphism) and unique. This is because we'll define $\pi_K=\star \circ \pi_N$, and by naturality of $\pi$, since this is really the only way we can define $\star$, so we have uniquness. Thus, $f'$ exists and is unique because $\tilde{f}$ and $\star$ were individually.

It remains to show $\star$ is well defined and $\pi_K=\star\circ \pi_N$. Take $\star:\bar{g}\mapsto gK$, and
$$\star(\bar{g_1})\star(\bar{g_2})=g_1Kg_2K=g_1g_2K=\star{(\overline{g_1g_2})=\star(\bar{g_1}\cdot \bar{g_2})}$$
remember bar is a homomorphism, thus the notation works out. Next, for any $g\in G$,
$$\pi_K(g)=gK=\star{(\bar{g})}=(\star\circ\pi_N)(g)$$